# Java concurrency exercise, implementing transfer of amount from one account to another

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

This is in continuation with my [synchronized implementation of a bank account in Java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/215616/synchronized-implementation-of-a-bank-account-in-java). I am trying to implement bank accounts repository and method to transfer money from one account to another. My implementation for the account and the repository looks like:

Account:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

/**
 * Class to represent an account, it also provides with methods to add and withdraw amount from the
 * account.
 *
 * @author Karan Khanna
 * @version 1.0
 * @since 3/17/2019
 */
public class Account {

    private final ReadWriteLock accountLock;

    private BigDecimal balance;

    private final String accountNumber;

    private final String accountHolder;

    public Account(String accountNumber, String accountHolder) {
        this.balance = new BigDecimal(0);
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.accountHolder = accountHolder;
        this.accountLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    }

    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public String getAccountHolder() {
        return accountHolder;
    }

    public ReadWriteLock getAccountLock() {
        return accountLock;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        this.accountLock.readLock().lock();
        try {
            return this.balance.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN).doubleValue();
        } finally {
            this.accountLock.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    public void addAmount(double amount) {
        this.accountLock.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            this.balance = this.balance.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(amount));
        } finally {
            this.accountLock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    public void withdrawAmount(double amount) {
        this.accountLock.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            this.balance = this.balance.subtract(BigDecimal.valueOf(amount));
        } finally {
            this.accountLock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

AccountsRepository:

```
import static java.lang.String.format;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.spituk.banking.app.repositories.AccountsRepository;
import org.spituk.banking.app.vo.Account;

/**
 * Map based account repository.
 *
 * @author Karan Khanna
 * @version 1.0
 * @since 3/17/2019
 */
public class AccountsRepositoryImpl implements AccountsRepository {

    private final static String SOURCE_ACCOUNT_DONOT_EXIST = "Source account number %s don't exist.";

    private final static String DESTINATION_ACCOUNT_DONOT_EXIST = "Destination account number %s don't exist.";

    private final static String NOT_ENOUGH_BALANCE = "Account number %s don't have enough balance.";

    private final Map<String, Account> accountMap;


    public AccountsRepositoryImpl() {
        this.accountMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void transferAmount(String accountNumberFrom, String  accountNumberTo, double amountToTransfer) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (accountMap.containsKey(accountNumberFrom)) {
            if(accountMap.get(accountNumberFrom).getBalance() < amountToTransfer) {
                if(accountMap.containsKey(accountNumberTo)) {
                    Account accountFrom = accountMap.get(accountNumberFrom);
                    Account accountTo = accountMap.get(accountNumberTo);
                    accountFrom.getAccountLock().writeLock().lock();
                    accountTo.getAccountLock().writeLock().lock();
                    try {
                        accountFrom.withdrawAmount(amountToTransfer);
                        accountTo.addAmount(amountToTransfer);
                    } finally {
                        accountFrom.getAccountLock().writeLock().unlock();
                        accountTo.getAccountLock().writeLock().unlock();
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(format(DESTINATION_ACCOUNT_DONOT_EXIST, accountNumberTo));
                }
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(format(NOT_ENOUGH_BALANCE, accountNumberFrom));
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(format(SOURCE_ACCOUNT_DONOT_EXIST, accountNumberFrom));
        }
    }
}
```

I am looking for feedback for the implementation.

Comment: In your transferAmount method you are locking/unlocking each account twice - before calling withdraw or add methods and inside them. You believe that setting the lock twice doubles the security effect?

Answer (score 1):

Some is personal taste, some is improving performance, some is avoiding deadlocks:

```
@Override
public void transferAmount(String accountNumberFrom, String  accountNumberTo, double amountToTransfer) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    synchronized(accountMap) {
        Account accountFrom = getAccount(accountNumberFrom, SOURCE_ACCOUNT_DONOT_EXIST);
        if (accountFrom.getBalance() >= amountToTransfer) {
            // BTW: I think that should be only > because balance==amount should be possible
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(format(NOT_ENOUGH_BALANCE, accountNumberFrom));
        }
        Account accountFrom = getAccount(accountNumberTo, DESTINATION_ACCOUNT_DONOT_EXIST);
        accountFrom.withdrawAmount(amountToTransfer);
        accountTo.addAmount(amountToTransfer);
    }
}

private Account getAccount(String accountNumber, String errorReason) {
    Account ret = accountMap.get(accountNumber);
    if (ret == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(format(errorReason, accountNumberFrom));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

In lack of knowledge about the details of this program, I changed everything to be synchronized. The reason is that otherwise it will lead to a deadlock, if there are two accounts each sending money to each other. Each thread might be able to aquire the first lock but then both will wait to get the second lock. In other words: You need to redesign your locking mechanism but without knowing more about the whole thing it's hard to come up with usable proposals.

What else have I changed:

- I created a method `getAccount` that returns the account or throws the `IllegalArgumentException` with the error message passed by the caller. This avoid code duplication and makes the code more readable by itself
- I personally prefer early returns and throwing exceptions. So instead of a big if-cascade that all need to pass before you do something, I prefer to check the inverted condition and return or throw immediately instead. I found that to be more understandable when looking at it after some time has passed.
- Instead of checking the existence of a key and the retrieval of the value in case it exists, it's simpler (and faster) to try to get the value and check for `null` unless `null` is a valid value (which is possible with `HashMap` but I doubt is the case in your application).

Some more thoughts:

- If `accountMap` can change (accounts added or deleted), you need to make sure that access to it is synchronized as well (with my change it already is but when you put it back to locks you need to take care of that). Otherwise you might transfer money to an account that stopped existing at that very moment and money "vanishes".
- Your account works with `BigDecimal` internally but you pass a `double` to `transferAmount`. That should be `BigDecimal` as well, otherwise you still end up with rounding problems. Your implementation of `getBalance` looks like you've ran into this problem already and your rounding is your workaround to fix the effect.

Comment: I didn't get the point for having a lock on the complete map. It will not allow multiple transactions to be processed in parallel even if they are related to different accounts.

Comment: @KaranKhanna Then why are you read- and write-locking said accounts if there is no parallel operation taking place?

Comment: I want to allow parallel operations on the accounts but if I take a lock on the whole map as you suggested, it will not allow parallel operations. Every thread will wait for the lock on the map to be released.

Comment: I have the locks on the accounts and not on the whole map.

Comment: @KaranKhanna I know, what you have done and why and I explained why that will lead to deadlocks if you keep it the way you implemented it, so I changed it to a more robust (but definetely slower) way. You need to rethink your locking mechanism.